# Chaining derived class methods to base class methods

Tags: c++, method-chaining

I am writing a library with chainable methods.

```
class Base {

  protected:
    int stepper=0;

  public:
    Base& baseMethod( void ) {
     Serial.println( stepper );
     return *this; 
    }
    virtual Base& derivedMethod( void ) =0;
    virtual Base& anotherDerivedMethod( void ) =0;
};

class Derived1 : public Base {

  public:
    Derived1& derivedMethod( void ) {
      stepper += 1;
      return *this;
    }

    Derived1& anotherDerivedMethod( void ) {
      stepper -= 1;
      return *this;
    }
};

class Derived2 : public Base {

  public:
    Derived2& derivedMethod( void ) {
      stepper += 2;
      return *this;
    }

    Derived2& anotherDerivedMethod( void ) {
      stepper -= 2;
      return *this;
    }

    Derived2& specialMethod( void ) {
      stepper *= 2;
      return *this;
    }
};
```

As you can see, `baseMethod()` returns a reference to a `Base` class, so I wouldn't expect to be able to then chain `derivedMethod()` or `anotherDerivedMethod()` to it, because the `Base` class should have no access to any derived methods.

However, in my test code (written for Arduino):

```
Derived1 myDerived1;
Derived2 myDerived2;

void setup() {

  Serial.begin( 9600 );

  // as expected, these work:

  myDerived1.derivedMethod().baseMethod();  // prints 1
  myDerived1.derivedMethod().derivedMethod().baseMethod();  // prints 3
  myDerived1.anotherDerivedMethod().baseMethod();  // prints 2
  myDerived1.anotherDerivedMethod().derivedMethod().baseMethod();   // prints 2

  myDerived2.specialMethod().baseMethod();  // prints 0
  myDerived2.specialMethod().derivedMethod().baseMethod();  // prints 2
  myDerived2.derivedMethod().specialMethod().baseMethod();  // prints 8

  // I wouldn't expect these to work, but I'm glad they do!

  myDerived1.baseMethod().derivedMethod();  // prints 2
  myDerived1.baseMethod().anotherDerivedMethod();  // prints 3

  myDerived2.baseMethod().derivedMethod();  // prints 8
  myDerived2.specialMethod().baseMethod().derivedMethod();  // prints 20

  // and as expected, these don't work:  

  myDerived2.baseMethod().specialMethod();  // prints 22
  myDerived2.baseMethod().derivedMethod().specialMethod();  // prints 24
}

void loop() { }
```

I *can* chain `derivedMethod()` and `anotherDerivedMethod()` to `baseMethod()`, but I *can't* chain `specialMethod()` to it.

```
method_chaining.ino:76:27: error: 'class Base' has no member named 'specialMethod'
```

The only difference I can see is that `specialMethod()` isn't mentioned in the `Base` class definition.  Is that why it doesn't work?

How can I chain derived class methods to base class methods?

Comment: I think CRTP may help with this, but haven't tried it myself: `class Derived: public Base<Derived>` and with the chained method in base defined as `template<typename T> T& Base<T>::baseMethod();`  Does that help?

Comment: If you declare functions in `Base`, then of course `Base` can access them. (And `baseMethod` does not return a pointer.)

Answer (score 1):

The whole point of virtual functions is being able to access derived functionality from a base reference or pointer - that is how polymorphism works. A `Base` reference has an underlying derived as its dynamic type. In fact because your `Base` is abstract (i.e. has pure virtual methods) its dynamic type cannot be itself (apart from some limited edge cases, such as during destruction) as you generally can't create objects of an abstract type.

For the same reason, calls pure virtual methods *have* to resolve (apart from again some limited circumstances) to calls to derived classes.

One exception to the above is when you attempt to call a pure virtual method from a destructor, where it is likely cause a runtime crash ('pure virtual method called').

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `baseMethod`'s return type is `Base` and it is not overriden in the derived classes. When calling `derived2.baseMethod().specialMethod()`, the compiler has to check if the class of the returned object, which is of static type `Base` as declared, contains a member function `specialMethod()`. This fails, even though the dynamic type contains it, but this is not known at compile time.

To make your example work, you have to override the function in the derived classes the same way as you do for the other member functions. However, all this only works as long as the static type is a derived type, because the compiler only checks this. If you don't intend to call `baseFunction` polymorphically through a `Base` pointer, you can you use static polymorphism:

```
template<typename T>
class Base {
  public:
    T& baseMethod( void ) {
         return *static_cast<T*>(this);
    }

    virtual Base& derivedMethod( void ) =0;
    virtual Base& anotherDerivedMethod( void ) =0;
};

class Derived1 : public Base<Derived1> {

  public:
    Derived1& derivedMethod( void ) {
      return *this;
    }

    Derived1& anotherDerivedMethod( void ) {
      return *this;
    }
};

class Derived2 : public Base<Derived2> {    
  public:
    Derived2& derivedMethod( void ) {
      return *this;
    }

    Derived2& anotherDerivedMethod( void ) {
      return *this;
    }

    Derived2& specialMethod( void ) {
      return *this;
    }
};
```

The drawback with this is that the derived classes do not share a common `Base<T>` parent, because `Base<Derived1> is a different type than`Base`. To have polymorphism, you have use templates`Base` everywhere.

I am not sure if I like the design. Protected members always make me think that this is implementation-sharing by inheritance, which is something you should avoid. I think